# C Code, search Function

Tags: c, function, search, struct

currently i am struggling trying to modify a basic search function.

Well, i made it work, and search the name of whatever the list contains, but if i want to search something by just a part of its name, for example if the name is Banana, and i input Bana, it would give me Banana.

Search Function :

```
void * PesquisaProdutos(PLISTA v1, int(*compara)(), void* valor) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < v1->posicao;i++)
    if ((*compara)(v1->cabeca[i], valor))
        return v1->cabeca[i];
    return NULL;
}
```

Compare Function :

```
int cmpDescricaoProduto(PLISTAPRODUTOS p, char* nome) {
    return strcmp(p->Descricao, nome) == 0;
}
```

and the main part :

```
printf("Insira o Nome: ");
            scanf("%s", &Descricao);
            getch();
            Pesquisar = PesquisaProdutos(&Produtos, cmpDescricaoProduto, Descricao);
            if (Pesquisar) printf("Descricao : %s", Descricao);
            else printf("Produto Inexistente");
            getch();
            break;
```

I would like to hear some ideas if possible, thank you.

Comment: Replace strcmp with strstr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strncmp` if you just want to check the first few characters of the string. It allows you to specify the maximum number of characters to check.

So:

```
strncmp ("banana", "ban", 3)
```

would be true.

Or you can use `strstr` to find a string somewhere *within* another string:

```
ststsr ("banana", "an")
```

would return a pointer to the first occurrence of `an` in the string `banana` (the second character in this case), or NULL if it's not in there.

So, your comparison function would then be something like (uncomment only the one you're interested in):

```
int cmpDescricaoProduto (PLISTAPRODUTOS p, char* nome) {
    // return strcmp (p->Descricao, nome) == 0;      // for exact match
    // return strncmp (p->Descricao, nome, 3) == 0;  // for close (3-char) match
    // return strstr (p->Descricao, nome) != NULL;   // for "contains" match
}
```

There *may* also be other string comparison function available to you in your environment, such as the case-insensitive ones, but they aren't technically part of the ISO C standard.

Comment: I understond, but imagine that i have a struct with name, age, etc. I ask the user to add the name, wich will send it to a list and store it.

Later, if i want to search that name, will i be able to do so with ststsr ? The user enters the name ange, and the search function goes and gets the name Angelina, wich is the name the user wanted to be searched.

Comment: @Diogo, yes, you need only provide a suitable comparison function. The one you have does a full match. Using one with `strstr` (I've added the code to my answer, see the third choice) will find one with the `nome` string anywhere within the `descrição`.